# Karma and requirejs: How to specify path from another project in requirejs.config?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, requirejs, karma-runner

I am using **karma.js** toghether with **require.js** in a VisualStudio solution. My solution has two projects, one for the code and one for the tests.

Following require configuration works fine for me if I reference libraries that are located in my Test.Project:

```
requirejs.config({   
  baseUrl: '/base',

  paths: {   
    'jquery': 'bower_components2/jquery/dist/jquery'    
  },

  deps: tests,   
  callback: window.__karma__.start
});
```

Here is part of my folder structure:

```
- Solution
  + Code.Project
    * App
    * bower_components1
  + Test.Project
    * App
    * bower_components2
    * karma.conf.js
```

**I would like to reference jquery from Code.Project** and not from **Test.Project**:

```
requirejs.config({   
  baseUrl: '/base',

  paths: {   
    'jquery': '../Code.Project/bower_components1/jquery/dist/jquery'    
  },

  deps: tests,   
  callback: window.__karma__.start
});
```

However, that does not work. Jquery can not be found and I get following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Script error for "jquery", needed by: App/app.spec.js
  http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
  at node_modules/requirejs/require.js:143
```

=> Is there a restriction that does not allow me to go upward from **/base** ? Should I use something different as baseUrl (I tried / and ./ but did not get it working)? Or is there some mistake in my relative path?

(Here is a full example on how to use requirejs with karma that I used as a starting point: https://github.com/kjbekkelund/karma-requirejs)

Answer (score 0):

I just found a related answer (see below).

It might also make more sense to put the karma.conf.js directly in the Solution folder and not inside the test project. Then I can directly enter "karma start" in the console. (The default path for the NuGet Package Manager Console / PowerShell is the solution folder.)

From [Karma and RequireJS getting files outside base url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29824193/karma-and-requirejs-getting-files-outside-base-url)

> As you wrote it yourself
>
> // Karma serves files under /base, which is the basePath from your     config file
>    baseUrl: '../',
>
> So it means if you want to be able to access files deeper than that you need to shift all your url with a:
>
> baseUrl: '../..',
>
> You could also use base/ which will be understood by karma as the basePath of your karmaConf.js
>
> For a better understanding on how the basePath of karma.conf and test-main.js works you can have a look at this: http://monicalent.com/blog/2015/02/11/karma-tests-angular-js-require-j/